# Using a setterbar to set text alignment while keeping the current vertical cursor bar position

Tags: dynamic, gui-construction

The code below generates a SetterBar that dynamically updates with the current text justification (where the vertical cursor bar is located) and allows you to change it to a new justification. See gif below.

```
SetterBar[
 Dynamic[e = 
   CurrentValue[NotebookSelection[], 
    TextAlignment], {SelectionMove[InputNotebook[], All, Cell]; 
    SetOptions[NotebookSelection[InputNotebook[]], 
     TextAlignment -> #]} &], {Left, Center, Right}]
```

The code contains the function `SelectionMove[InputNotebook[], All, Cell]`.  The problem with keeping that function in the code is that I lose the current vertical curser bar position.  See gif below.

[image]

I would like to keep the current cursor bar position where its at, but if remove that function the setter bar doesn't work anymore.  Do you have any ideas?

Comment: BTW... "Introduction to Toolbars".in the documentation has an example like this one.  They include `SelectionMove[InputNotebook[],All,Cell]` as I did.  However, this is not how just justification bars are setup in word processors.    They always keep the current cursor position.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is the inability to easily get the input cell. I have a way, but it's slow and convoluted...

```
inputCell[] :=
 Replace[Developer`CellInformation@InputNotebook[],
  inf_List :>
   Replace[
    Position[
     FEPacketExecute["NotebookGetLayoutInformationPacket", 
      InputNotebook[]],
     Global`CellInformation["CellSerialNumber" /. First@inf,
      ___]
     ], {
     {{i_, ___}, ___} :>
      Cells[InputNotebook[]][[i]],
     _ -> None
     }
    ]
  ]
```

Then it's trivial to set this up:

```
SetterBar[
 Dynamic[
  EvaluationCell[];
  CurrentValue[inputCell[], TextAlignment],
  CurrentValue[inputCell[], TextAlignment] = #; &
  ],
 {Left, Center, Right}]
```

Note that we need the `EvaluationCell[]` in there so the `Dynamic` tracking actually happens.

Comment: It seems like there must be an easier way to do this.  Would it be any easier to have this functionality using a button or buttonbar instead of a setterbar?

Comment: The fundamental issue is just that you can't use EvaluationCell so you need a way to target the input cell. If you don't use a Dynamic construct it won't eat the front end so much though, so in that case a button might make sense. In terms of the menu, check the MenuSetup.tr to figure out how they do it. I'll check that when I have my copy of Mathematica open again. Should be a FE token or packet.

Comment: Use AbuttingLeftRight. I think that's the central appearance.

Comment: ImageSize -> Automatic will shrink the buttons to their min possible size. Sorry to just get to this now.

Comment: My guess is at the Box level there are differences in BaseStyle and FrameMargins. Not sure if it qualifies as a bug.

Answer (score 2):

This works.

```
SetterBar[
 Dynamic[e = CurrentValue[NotebookSelection[], TextAlignment], {
    SetOptions[SelectedCells[][[1]], TextAlignment -> #]} &], {Left, 
  Center, Right}]
```

Comment: Seems good. I was searching for SelectedCells functionality. Do you still need the whole Dynamic expression or would CurrentValue[SelectedCells[][[1]], TextAlignment] suffice?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are asking, but I believe Dynamic is needed so that the button updates using this second argument of dynamic upon each press.

Comment: Sorry, I meant I don't know if you need the second argument to Dynamic. Just wrapping Dynamic around that expression might suffice, given CurrentValue routes to a SetOptions expression I think.

Comment: Oh I understand.  However, I'm not able to make it work without both arguments.  I'm not sure why.  However, what you are saying makes sense to me.  : /  I think that second argument is needed as it acts as a trigger.