# Simplifying the access to the change of the output font

Tags: programming

This command seems to work for changing the font used in output

```
$PrePrint = Style[#, FontFamily -> "Arial"] &;
```

Is there a way to make a button which can in a way or an other list all available fonts, size, color when using such a command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm uncertain if you want to know what options you can use or if you want to know how to build a button to apply the styling.

If you want to list all of your system fonts, you can get them via `$FontFamilies`.

`FontColor` can be any color you like, so just choose some `Hue[h,s,b]` value (I find this somewhat easier to use that `RGBColor[r,g,b]`).

`FontSize` is any positive integer

`FontWeight` can be `Bold`, `Plain`, or `DemiBold` (for some fonts).

If you want flexible auto-styling just create a `$styleSpec` variable you can change at whim.

```
$styleSpec={
 FontFamily->"Arial",
 FontColor->Hue[.6,.5,.5],
 FontWeight->"DemiBold"
 };
$PrePrint = Style[#, Sequence@@$styleSpec] &;
```

That ought to do it.

If you want to do it in a button you can do so via either a `SelectedCells` mechanism or via `FrontEndTokenExecute`, the first of which is seen [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/133881/using-a-setterbar-to-set-text-alignment-while-keeping-the-current-vertical-curso).